# Why am I getting a key error when submitting a form from another form?

Tags: python, forms, flask, error-handling, key

Basically, I have a few forms. And they all work as they're supposed to. I've been trying to figure out a way to write to an google spreadsheet using google API. The user selects a date, the techs name and a account id in the modal and submits the form. When the user submits the form, the information is put into the google spread as it should. The problem comes after submitting when I get a key error. The information is still put into the google spread, but the page errors out regardless.

**This is the error message I am getting:**

```
2023-05-11 17:33:42,157: Error running WSGI application
2023-05-11 17:33:42,159: werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
2023-05-11 17:33:42,159: KeyError: 'select_installer'
2023-05-11 17:33:42,159:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2095, in __call__
2023-05-11 17:33:42,160:     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
2023-05-11 17:33:42,160: 
2023-05-11 17:33:42,160:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2080, in wsgi_app
2023-05-11 17:33:42,160:     response = self.handle_exception(e)
2023-05-11 17:33:42,160: 
2023-05-11 17:33:42,160:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
2023-05-11 17:33:42,160:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2023-05-11 17:33:42,160: 
2023-05-11 17:33:42,161:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1525, in full_dispatch_request
2023-05-11 17:33:42,161:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2023-05-11 17:33:42,161: 
2023-05-11 17:33:42,161:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1523, in full_dispatch_request
2023-05-11 17:33:42,161:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2023-05-11 17:33:42,161: 
2023-05-11 17:33:42,162:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1509, in dispatch_request
2023-05-11 17:33:42,162:     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
2023-05-11 17:33:42,162: 
2023-05-11 17:33:42,162:   File "/home/wildstarapps/mysite/ibt_blueprint.py", line 63, in home
2023-05-11 17:33:42,163:     installer = installer_info(request.form['select_installer'])[0]
2023-05-11 17:33:42,163: 
2023-05-11 17:33:42,163:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 375, in __getitem__
2023-05-11 17:33:42,163:     raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
```

**Here is my html:**

```
<div class="card card--avatar">
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('profile-modal').style.display='flex'" class="btn-profile"
          aria-label="interactive button">
          <svg aria-hidden="true" width="21" height="5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path
              d="M2.5 0a2.5 2.5 0 1 1 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 1 0-5Zm8 0a2.5 2.5 0 1 1 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 1 0-5Zm8 0a2.5 2.5 0 1 1 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 1 0-5Z"
              fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd" />
          </svg>
        </button>
        <div class="card--avatar-top card--lg">
          <img class="avatar"
            src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/profile_pics/'+ installer.profile_pic )}}">
          <h1>
            <span>Report for</span><br>
            {{ installer.f_name }}
            {{ installer.l_name }}
          </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card--avatar-bottom card--sm" role="tablist" aria-label="Time Tracking Cross sections">
          <button name="all-tab" id="tab-all" class="btn tab active"
            onclick="update_stats(this.attributes['name'].value)">
            All
          </button>
          <button name="day-tab" id="tab-daily" class="btn tab" onclick="update_stats(this.attributes['name'].value)">
            Day
          </button>
          <button name="week-tab" id="tab-weekly" class="btn tab" onclick="update_stats(this.attributes['name'].value)">
            Week
          </button>
          <button name="month-tab" id="tab-monthly" class="btn tab"
            onclick="update_stats(this.attributes['name'].value)">
            Month
          </button>
          <form method="POST" name="date_form" id="date_form">
            <input type="hidden" name="select_installer" value="{{ installer.id }}">
            <input id="day_selected" name="day_selector" value="{{ date_input }}" type="date" class="date-selector"
              onchange="submitForm()">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

<div class="card timecard" style="display: none;" id="google-reviews">
            <div class="card--sm timecard--top">
            </div>
            <div class="timecard--bottom card--lg">
              <div class="timecard--title">
                <h2>
                  5 Star Reviews
                </h2>
                {% if session.user_info.role|lower == 'admin' %}
                <button onclick="document.getElementById('review-modal').style.display='flex'" class="btn" aria-label="interactive button">
                  <svg aria-hidden="true" width="21" height="5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path
                      d="M2.5 0a2.5 2.5 0 1 1 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 1 0-5Zm8 0a2.5 2.5 0 1 1 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 1 0-5Zm8 0a2.5 2.5 0 1 1 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 1 0-5Z"
                      fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd" />
                  </svg>
                </button>
                {% endif %}
              </div>
              <div class="timecard--amt">
                <p class="current">
                  {{ review_count }}
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

<form method="POST" id="installer-submit">
  <input type="hidden" name="day_selector" value="{{ date_input }}">
  <div id="user-modal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content modal-card modal-animate" style="max-width:600px">
      <div class="modal-container">
        <div class="modal-section">
          <label for="select-installer">Please select a tech:</label>
          <select name="select_installer" id="select-installer" onchange="submit_installer_form()">
            {% for installers in all_installers %}
                {% if installers['id'] == installer['id'] %}
                    <option value="{{ installer['id'] }}" selected="">{{ installer['f_name'] + ' ' + installer['l_name'] }}</option>
                {% else %}
                    <option value="{{ installers['id'] }}">{{ installers['f_name'] + ' ' + installers['l_name'] }}</option>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </select>
          <div class="buttons">
            <button onclick="document.getElementById('user-modal').style.display='none'" type="button"
            class="modal-button-close">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<form method="POST" id="review-form">
  <div id="review-modal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content modal-card modal-animate" style="max-width:600px">
      <div class="modal-container">
        <div class="modal-section">
          <label for="review-date">Review Date:</label>
          <input type="month" id="review-date" name="review_date">
          <label for="tech-select">Choose tech(s):</label>
          <select id="tech-select" name="selected_tech">
            {% for installers in all_installers %}
            <option value="{{ installers['l_name'] + ',' + ' ' + installers['f_name'] }}">{{ installers['f_name'] + ' ' + installers['l_name'] }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
          </select>
          <label for="account-id">Account ID:</label>
          <input type="text" id="account-id" name="account_id">
          <div class="buttons">
            <button type="submit" name="review_submit" id="review-submit" value="Submit Review" class="modal-button-submit">Submit</button>
            <button onclick="document.getElementById('review-modal').style.display='none'" type="button"
            class="modal-button-close">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Here is my blueprint:**

```
if request.method == "POST":
        review_date = request.form.get("review_date")
        selected_tech = request.form.get("selected_tech")
        review_account_id = request.form.get("account_id")
        if review_date and selected_tech and review_account_id:
            parsed_date = datetime.strptime(review_date, "%Y-%m")
            month = parsed_date.strftime("%-m")
            year = parsed_date.strftime("%Y")
            # Get the last row in the worksheet
            last_row = len(gReviewWorksheet.get_all_values()) + 1
            # Append data to the certain row
            gReviewWorksheet.update(f"A{last_row}", month)
            gReviewWorksheet.update(f"B{last_row}", year)
            gReviewWorksheet.update(f"C{last_row}", selected_tech)
            gReviewWorksheet.update(f"F{last_row}", review_account_id)
        installer_hours_dict = {}
        installer = installer_info(request.form['select_installer'])[0]
        selected_date = datetime.strptime(request.form['day_selector'], '%Y-%m-%d')
        hours = hoursDf.query(f'''Month == "{selected_date.month}" & Year == "{selected_date.year}"''').to_dict('records')
        reviews = gReviewDf.query(f'''Month == "{selected_date.month}" & Year == "{selected_date.year}" & Tech_ID == "{installer['paylocity_id']}"''').to_dict('records')
        review_count = len(reviews)
```

Comment: What do you expect `request.form['select_installer']` to be? There's no input with that name in the HTML.

Comment: There's also no `day_selector`, which you use on the next line. Are these supposed to come from the spreadsheet? Why would you expect them to be in `request.form`, which just contains the inputs from the form?

Comment: Only one form can be submitted at a time. Python can only get values from the form that was submitted, not other forms on the same page.

Comment: I updated the html to have more code to aid in helping me find an answer. If you need to see more of the python function, let me know.

Comment: I see a lot of code above, but no SQL. Are you sure the <sql> tag is relevant?

Comment: SQL is included in functions but since I'm not showing functions containing the queries I will remove the tag!

Comment: You need to combine the two forms into one form. Like I said above, you can only process one form at a time.